# Use persistent external program for occasional input / output translation in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm writing some Scala code that needs to make use of a external command line program for string translation. The external program takes many minutes to start up, then listens for data on stdin (terminated by newline), converts the data, and prints the converted data to stdout (again terminated by newline). It will remain alive forever until it receives a SIGINT.

For simplicity, let's assume the external command runs like this:

`$ convert
input1
output2
input2
output2
$`

`convert`, `input1`, and `input2` were all typed by me; `output1` and `output2` were written by the program to stdout. I typed Control-C at the end to return to the shell.

In my Scala code, I'd like to start up this external program, and keep it running in the background (because it is costly to startup, but cheap to keep running once it's initialized), while providing three methods to the rest of my program with an API like:

`def initTranslation(): Unit
def translate(input: String): String
def stopTranslation(): Unit`

`initTranslation` should start up the external program and keep it running in the background.
`translate` should put the `input` argument on the stdin of the  external program (followed by newline), wait for output (followed by newline), and then return the output.
`stopTranslation` should send SIGINT to the external program.

I've worked with Java and Scala external process management before, but don't have too much experience with Java pipes, but am not 100% sure how to hook this all up. In particular, I've read that there are subtle gotchas with regards to deadlocks when I/O pipes get hooked up in situations similar to this. I'm sure I'll need some `Thread` to watch start up and watch over the background process in `initTranslation`, some piping to send a `String` to stdin followed by blocking to wait for receiving data and a newline on stdout in `translate`, then some sort of termination of the external program in `stopTranslation`.

I'd like to achieve this with as much pure Scala as possible, though I realize that this may require some bits of the Java I/O library. I also do not want to use any third party Scala or Java libraries (anything outside java.*, javax.* or scala.*)

What would these three methods look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this is quite a bit easier than I first expected. I had been misled by various posts and recommendations (off SO) which had suggested that this would be more complex.

Caveats to this solution:

- All Java. Yes, I know I mentioned that I'd rather use the Scala standard library, but this is sufficiently succinct that I think it warrants an answer.
- Limited error handling - among other things, if the external program explodes and reports errors to stderr, I'm not handling that. Certainly, that could be added on later.
- Usage of `var` for storage of local variables. Clearly, `var` is frowned upon for best-practice Scala use, but this example illustrates the object state needed, and you can structure your variables in your own programs as you like.
- No thread-safety. If you need thread-safety, because multiple threads might call any of the following methods, use some synchronization constructs (like the `synchronized` keyword in the translate method) to protect yourself.

Solution:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.lang.Process
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder

var process: Process = _
var outputReader: BufferedReader = _

def initTranslation(): Unit = {
  process = new ProcessBuilder("convert").start()
  outputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))
}

def translate(input: String): String = {
  // write path to external program
  process.getOutputStream.write(cryptoPath.getBytes)
  process.getOutputStream.write(System.lineSeparator.getBytes)
  process.getOutputStream.flush()
  // wait for input from program
  outputReader.readLine()
}

def stopTranslation(): Unit = {
  process.destroy()
}
```